# Center Content horizontally and vertically in <main> Part not on Full Page

Tags: html, css, centering

so I already created a navigation bar in the `<header>` part and a footer on my website. I also have a `<div class="UUDiv">` with a paragraph and a headline in it in my `<main>` part. Now, I want to center `<div class="UUDiv">` horizontally and vertically but only in the main part. With the following code i only centered it in the center of the whole page, so my Div overlaps with my footer...Here is my Code: \

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.UUDiv {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<header class="RestHeader">
  <nav class="navigation">Navigation...with
    <ul>
      <li> List </li>
    </ul>etc.</nav>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="UUDiv">
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="footer">Footer...with
    <ul>
      <li> Another List </li>
    </ul> etc.</div>
</footer>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you use `position: absolute` you'll need to set position of footer too

Comment: @RicardoPontual Ok I tried to position my footer relative but then it is just over my main content. I also tried to position my <main>  relative, but then the content goes out of my window...only a few lines are at the top of my window...It is a bit weird and i am new to html and css so i dont really know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of positioning your div absolute, you could use flexbox for this.
Giving your `<main>` a `display: flex` and centering it's content like so:

```
main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.UUDiv {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Then it will stay centered inside your `<main>`.

The full example:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.UUDiv {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="RestHeader">
  <nav class="navigation">Navigation...with
    <ul>
      <li> List </li>
    </ul>etc.</nav>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="UUDiv">
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="footer">Footer...with
    <ul>
      <li> Another List </li>
    </ul> etc.</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it is quite similar to the one above, so yours should work too but I have the same problem with my footer above. I try to figure out another way to make my footer stay down at the bottom of my page so that your answer works.

Answer (score 1):

Try The below Code Snippet.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.UUDiv {
  text-align: center;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
  
 ul{
   display:flex;
   list-style:none;
 }
 ul li{
  margin-left:1rem;
 }
```

```html
<header class="RestHeader">
  <nav class="navigation">Navigation...with
    <ul>
      <li> List </li>
      <li> List </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <div class="UUDiv">
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</main>
<footer>
  <div class="footer">Footer...with
    <ul>
      <li> Another List </li>
      <li> Another List </li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks first of all. I think this should work, but for me it kind of doesnt...So I see the content and it isnt overlapping something but it isnt in the center as well...It is, with a bit of distance, under my navigation bar.

Comment: I now figured it out why it isnt working for me. I have a footer at the bottom of my page which is made like shown in my body with min-heigt 100%, display flex and flex-direction column. In my footer i have margin-top auto so it is always pushed down. This margin now takes away the space where my content should be.